# ReactJS/Next.js: CRA Proxy Does Not Work With Next.js (Attempting To Route API Request To Express server)

Tags: reactjs, express, create-react-app, next.js

I'm currently upgrading a vanilla React app to use Next.js (version 7.0.0). The app was originally built with Create-React-App and utilizes the proxy built in to CRA's server.

In development my React app runs on **port 3000** and I have an Express server running on **port 5000**. Prior to adding Next.js I'd been using a **proxy object** within the **package.json** file to route API requests to the server.

**API request:**

```
const res = await axios.get('/api/request')
```

**Proxy object in package.json:**

```
"proxy": {
  "/api/*": {
    "target": "http://localhost:5000"
  }
}
```

This had been working great, but with Next.js I'm now getting an error:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/api/request 404 (Not Found)
```

**^ This is supposed to be pointing to locahost:5000 (my server)**

Does anyone know how I might be able to route API requests from a React/Next.js client to an Express server running on a different port?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, so I've figured this out. You can create a Node.js proxy for Express by using [http-proxy-middleware](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-proxy-middleware)

You can then configure the *target* option to proxy requests to the correct domain:

```
const proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware')

app.use('/api', proxy({ target: 'http://localhost:5000', changeOrigin: true }));
```

Comment: Could you please clarify your answer more? Did you add middleware to backend? or to nextjs?

Comment: To the custom nextjs server.js file

Comment: Anyone looking for more resources on this: there's an [issue](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/2281) on the Next.js repo for context, and an official [example Next.js app](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/master/examples/with-custom-reverse-proxy) implementing this solution.

Comment: What if I have a completely separate folder of the backend which runs API on port = 8080.  What should I do to make an api request to it from my nextjs frontend using path /api?